# UItableView Reload take time while using NSLayoutconstraints in Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have used a `UITableView` with multiple types of fields of `UITableViewCells`. Each cell having different fields. I have used `NSLayoutContraints` visual formatting language for auto layout. While reloading `UITableView` takes huge time and getting `NSLayoutContraints` Error.

> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

As I am using Xamarin studio I'm not able to set the symbolic breakpoint. Please guide me.

Comment: Please add all your constraints also.

Comment: using dynamic data so contraints are added to for particular field.

Comment: Are you able to add your code?

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are special in uitableview cells.
You must add your ui items to the cell's ContentView, not the cell's View.
And you must add constraints between ui items and the cell's ContentView.

You must have 0 unsatisfiable constraint at the end. It's very tricky to get constraints working, so you should use XIB and edit them using xcode through xamarin studio. xcode will tell you if your constraints are ok.

If reloading items is slow, verify that you used reusable cells in your table.

This is not Xamarin specific. It's iOS specific.